# Is that a way to sync Drupal databases

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm working on an existing website. So before I started I copied all files and database to my local environment. So far so good. To port the changes over I'd planned on using features. For a number of reasons the project got slightly off track I can't no longer migrate the features using the `features` module. Other than trying to fix why I can't port the features to the live site, I've been wondering whether is there a way to sync the two databases (*effectively moving all the content - nodes, taxonomies and users - from the live site to the local site*). I've tried **Migrate Drupal to Drupal** but the content wasn't imported. (I'm also looking at why it didn't work) but my question now is:

Are there any options to do it ? How ? (Other than Migrate Drupal to Drupal or using Features to migrate the features over)?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't dump the database from live site, and then restore it in the local server?

Comment: Then I'd lose all changes (new modules installed, configurations, roles, product types, etc) that I've created on the local that is not currently present in the live site.

Comment: You don't specify why you can't use Features. Maybe you could export all those changes made in your local with Features. Second, make the dump from live and restore in local. Third, restore your Features in local.

Comment: @typologist I'm still trying to get Features to work within y setup, hence I'm investigating different options. I'm using Features Commerce, however its not comprehensive so not all required features are transferred over and the ones it does breaks the receiving Drupal installation. Like I said, I'm still investigating the why of it, but was hoping there were alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other options you can explore, apart from the ones you have already mentioned:

[drupal sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_sync)
The present module allows synchronizing content among multiple websites.
Supported entity types: node and taxomony, menu items.

[deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy)
The Deploy module is designed to allow users to easily stage and preview content for a Drupal site. Deploy automatically manages dependencies between entities (like node references). It is designed to have a rich API which can be easily extended to be used in a variety of content staging situations.